# Similar questions box keeps popping in and out

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, asking-questions, similar-questions

Today I was trying to [post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on Stack Overflow. While I was typing, the "Similar Questions" box (between the title and body) kept popping up and then disappearing again, causing the focused text area where I was typing the question body to shift up and down the screen in a very annoying way — not unlike certain websites you may have encountered where ads are constantly loaded and unloaded making it almost impossible to read whatever content you are looking at.

In this case, it happened 10 or 15 times while I was composing the body of my question.  As a matter of fact, it's happened 4 or 5 times here on meta as well typing this very question.

I don't remember this being an issue in the past.  Did something change recently?  Can this be fixed please or is there a setting I can enable to stop it from happening?

Comment: I get this happening to me in Chrome on my Mac. It also exists in Teams.

Comment: This was happening to me yesterday using Firefox 68.0.1 on Win 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now. We made a change that was supposed to hide the Similar Questions block in the guided wizard mode, but it ended up being a bit overeager in traditional mode.

Thanks for the report!